# loop autoit script until end of doc

Tags: windows, autoit

I have an autoit script that basicly copies the first line of text, and then pastes it again in the same line. I would like to do this over and over until the end of the document. Any suggestions?

```
Run("notepad.exe filename.txt")
WinWaitActive("Untitled - Notepad")
Send("+{END}")
Send("^C")
Sleep (1000)
Send("{END}")
Sleep (1000)
Send(" ")
Send("^V")
Send("{HOME}")
Send("{DOWN}")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
$filename = "filename.txt"

Run("notepad.exe " & $filename)
WinWaitActive($filename & " - Notepad")

$lines= StringRegExp(FileRead($filename), @CR, 3)
$count = UBound($lines)

For $i = 0 To $count
    Send("+{END}")
    Send("^C")
    Sleep (1000)
    Send("{END}")
    Sleep (1000)
    Send(" ")
    Send("^V")
    Send("{HOME}")
    Send("{DOWN}")
Next
```

You have to wait for the Window with the filename in it's title. If the filename has spaces inside, you need to put quotes around the parameter after notepad.exe.

Somehow you need to get the count of line numbers. I just read the whole file with AutoIt and search for a "carriage return". The resulting Array has the size of the line numbers. That number is then used in a For-...-To-...-Loop.

You can decrease the sleep-times to 100ms. And it would be much easier to use FileReadLine and probably FileWriteLine to do your task, as FileReadLine can be used until the end of file is reached. It will set @error to -1. See the [documentation](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/FileReadLine.htm) for more info.